Python Selenium How to set the specific microphone device in different Chrome
I want to set the specific microphone device in different Chrome, e.g. Chrome A using "Microphone A", Chrome B using "Microphone B". I know the Firefox can doing this using
profile.set_preference("media.default.audio_capture", "Microphone A")


However, I cannot find any information of this in Chrome. How to make it in Chrome using Python Selenium
I tried to using this but not working


prefs = {

    "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 1,


"mediaDevices.defaultAudioInput": "Microphone A" 

}


should be "media.default_audio_capture_device"  See here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/32352ad08ee673a4d43e8593ce988b224f6482d3/chrome/common/pref_names.cc

@browsermator Yes you are right!, thank you so much

prefs = {

"profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 1,
"media.default_audio_capture_device": "Device ID" 
}

Device ID can be found on Chrome setting using Dev tool. In my case, the microphone A is
{0.0.1.00000000}.{6c057a49-4423-4c97-8806-f51e62014e85}
Write the code like this:
 prefs = {

"profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 1,
"media.default_audio_capture_device": "{0.0.1.00000000}.{6c057a49-4423-4c97-8806-f51e62014e85}" 
}

